# Front-end-node - error#: Cannot infer the root project id

Tags: substrate

I am following the tutorial Creating an ink!Project - https://substrate.dev/substrate-contracts-workshop/#/0/creating-an-ink-project, and have successfully tested the `flipper` contract.

When I build the contract using `cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 contract build` I get an error:

```
ERROR: Cannot infer the root project identer link description here
```

[image]

Even though I have researched this issue, cannot work out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build the Substrate `node-template` using `cargo-contract`.
**Cargo Contract** can only be used to build Smart contract like the example you mentioned (*flipper*).

For the node-template run `cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 build --release`

Comment: Yeah, if your goal is to build the contract you need to be in in the directory for the contract's project when you run this command `cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 contract build`.

Comment: In the tutorial I should be able to see a 'target folder' which contains this .wasm file - although have searched and cannot see this..

target
└── flipper.wasm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, 'when I run 'cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 build --release' it compiles successfully!